# Math courses at the undergraduate or graduate level that can be self-studied?

Tags: soft-question

I've taken courses whereby, given the exams, homework, and textbook, a student could pass the course with little class interaction.

Which undergrad or post-grad level courses can be self-studied and still develop a similar understanding and appreciation as that of a traditional course? For example, maybe the first three undergrad Calculus courses, whereas a first or second course in Linear Algebra might have proofs which greatly benefit from a live professor's explanation as opposed to a textbook.

Comment: I don't think there are any courses that can't be self-studied. Anyway, this question is a bit too subjective in my opinion. It depends on what kind of "understanding and appreciation" you are looking for.

Comment: ohh closure..but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Differential Equations, such as ODE and PDE are possible. Don't forget Vector Calculus (not sure if included in your "three semester of Calculus") and Elementary Probability Theory (topics include Central Limit Theorem, Joint PDFS, Conditional Probability, Counting techniques etc...).

Also Complex Analysis (at the very basic level, including topics like Contour Integration which is still in the domain of "Calculus" ) and maybe specialized topics like Mathematical Biology (overlap with ODE/PDE)

Some basic Number Theory and Modern Euclidean Geometry might be possible. Maybe not some of the geometry problems because I've noticed most have very poor wording. So Geometry with Linear Algebra is still possible, though you may have a hard time if you are rusty with high school geometry

Courses heavily proof-based aren't really friendly self-studiedable. I mean you can, but a teacher will help a lot.